# @times-components/article-list npm install not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to npm install the @times-components/article-list so that I can use the component.
It unfortunately doesn't want to install. These are the error messages I am getting.  Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Wanted the package to correctly install. I have updated Node, NPM, and React

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.